# How to display higher order terms first?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to make Mathematica display higher order terms first? I want x^3 to come before x^2 etc. but this is what I get:

```
In[1]:= A = x^2 + x
Out[1]= x + x^2

In[2]:= B = 2 x + 3
Out[2]= 3 + 2 x

In[3]:= A + B
Out[3]= 3 + 3 x + x^2
```

I really just want to reverse the display of terms. How can I get something like this?

```
In[3]:= A + B
Out[3]= x^2 + 3 x + 3
```

Multivariate polynomials display curiously as well.  Despite the order of the terms of this expression:

```
x^2 + y^4 + 3 x + 3 + xy^2 + y + y^3
```

I get

```
3 + 3 x + x^2 + xy^2 + y + y^3 + y^4
```

I'm not entirely sure of the best way of displaying this, but I know I want higher order terms first.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

`TraditionalForm` may help you

```
3+x+x^2//TraditionalForm
```

displays as

```
x^2+x+3
```

but you should be cautious because `TraditionalForm` items cannot have any further sensible math done to them. For example, because of `TraditionalForm` has higher precedence than `=` it turned the polynomial into traditional form and then assigned the result.

```
A=3+x+x^2//TraditionalForm
Solve[A==0,x]
```

And then the calculation on that traditional form gives you:

```
{{x->1/2 (-1-Sqrt[-11+4 TraditionalForm^(-1)[0]},
 {x->1/2 (-1+Sqrt[-11+4 TraditionalForm^(-1)[0]}}
```

But if you carefully keep separate those things that are pretty to look at from those things you are using to do further calculations with then this may work for you.